# (Hints please) Constructing a measurable set with the following property.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\delta >0$, $I_\delta=(-\delta,\delta)\in\mathbb{R}$, and $0\leq\alpha\leq\beta\leq1$, what hints do you have that would help me figure out how to construct a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that as $\delta\to0$ we have the upper and lower limits of $\frac{m(E\cap I_\delta)}{2\delta}$ are $\beta$ and $\alpha$ (respectively)? (I'm assuming here that $m$  is taken to be Lebesgue measure, but I could be mistaken.)

(This problem is found in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis text, chapter 7, problem 2.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: It's easier to think about if you assume that $E=-E$ and you calculate the intersections with $[0,\delta)$ instead. Further, if $E=\bigcup_n [a_n,b_n)$ where $b_{n+1}< a_n<  b_n\to 0$, then the upper limits can be calculated using just $E\cap[0,b_n)$ while the lower limits can be calculated using just $E\cap [0,a_n)$.